# My Websites Are A Mess in Zoom 100%+

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I always have this problem with the websites I develop. I used media queries with the max resolution :

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 1920px) {}
```

Is there any way to ensure content displays correctly if a page is zoomed to say 150%? Many of my elements have absolute positioning so if I used max width for other elements I would still have issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes ... a big step in the right direction is to start using `em` instead of `px` to set your media queries:

```
@media only screen and (max-width:120em){}
```

This accounts for zoom, whereas setting it by pixels gets all distorted as you zoom in. [Here is a good article that talks about why to use `em` instead of `px`](http://blog.cloudfour.com/the-ems-have-it-proportional-media-queries-ftw/), and [here is a good resource for px-to-em conversions](http://pxtoem.com/).